# can you assign something to return for comparing?

Tags: javascript, function

in the following example, something was assigned to return. I'd like to know the rule in writing this.

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {

  return str.slice(str.length - target.length) === target;
}

confirmEnding("He has to give me a new name", "name");
```

Is it the same logic as: if what is before === equal what it after it return true and if not return false?

Comment: Hard to know what you're asking here.  Yes, your `return` will give you a boolean, but that should be obvious, but that's an odd comparison.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: converts above codes to `function confirmEnding(str, target) {let temp = str.slice(str.length - target.length); return temp === target;}`, then study [Javascript MDN: String.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice),  you will understand how this function works.

Comment: thank you for replying. what I mean is, I found this example in freeCodeCamp and I'd like to know what does it mean to assign something to return.

Comment: @SALAHLASHIN There is no assignment here; `===` (and `==`) are equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The same function can be written in many different ways.  And it's not actually called an assignment.  `a = b` is an assignment that evaluates to the new value of `a` after the assignment is complete.  But `a == b` (or `a === b`) is an equality (the latter, `strict` equality) test that evaluates to `true` or `false`.

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  return str.slice(str.length - target.length) === target;
}
```

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  if (str.slice(str.length - target.length) === target) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  return str.slice(str.length - target.length) === target 
    ? true
    : false
}
```

```js
const confirmEnding = (str, target) => str.slice(str.length - target.length) === target;
```

Comment: (Noting for the OP that only the first or last would be how you'd write it IRL.)